# how combobox expand downward in metro app windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, combobox, windows-store-apps

I am working with metro app Windows 8. I am facing problem with using combobox when that populate in upward or center direction while it should be in downward direction.

Here is my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CBFolderItem" SelectedValuePath="folderId" 
DisplayMemberPath="Description" Canvas.Left="394" Canvas.Top="150" Width="335"/>`
```

Comment: How about you show everyone what you've tried?

Comment: ` <ComboBox x:Name="CBFolderItem" SelectedValuePath="folderId" DisplayMemberPath="Description"    Canvas.Left="394" Canvas.Top="150" Width="335"/>`

Comment: A combobox will render it's DropDown contents based on it's vertical location and the space available surrounding it. I don't believe there's a way to force the behavior you're requiring without either a.) Making a custom control. or b.) Provide enough space available below the control to let it render that direction naturally.